# How do you have NAT always assign the same IP address in VMWare Fusion?

Tags: nat, vmware-fusion

I currently have 4 virtual machines I've created using out-of-the-box VMWare Fusion on my MacBook Pro.  They are all configured with NAT for the networking and therefore get a 192.168.43.xxx IP address.  I would like to force NAT/DHCP to always give the same machine a set IP address.  So machine 1 would always be 192.168.43.129, machine 2 would always be 192.168.43.130, etc.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAT and DHCP aren't tied to each other in VMWare.

When you set up NAT networking, you're just putting the guest on a network (vmnet8 if I recall) that happens to have DHCP server on it.  There's nothing stopping you from taking over the job of IP address management from VMWare.

Unless there is a specific reason that you want to do this via DHCP, you can just assign static addresses in each guest using the correct network setup.  Get an address once via DHCP to get the values or look at your VMWare networking configuration.

Comment: I like this approach. It makes perfect sense and it's not something I thought of intuitively out the gate. Thanks for not only answering the question, but reminding me of the perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.stereoplex.com/two-voices/vmware-fusion-guests-with-a-static-ip) with a little research... hope it helps.

Comment: Nice, so the website has you set a fixed-address for each host.  I'll try this out and see if it works.